# Draw SpreadsheetTable at custom location on the canvas

Tags: python-2.7, reportlab

I am using `SpreadsheetTable` to print tables that span multiple pages. However, once I build the story, the table always shows up in the middle of the page. I want to position it to my custom location on the canvas. How to achieve this? The `Table` and `LongTable` classes too didn't have the positioning arguments.

Adding my code:

```
import random

from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4, landscape
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph, Table, Flowable, PageBreak, LongTable
from reportlab.lib.units import mm
from reportlab.platypus.flowables import Spacer, Image
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet, ParagraphStyle
from reportlab.lib import colors
from spreadsheettable import SpreadsheetTable

doc = SimpleDocTemplate("customFlow.pdf", pagesize=A4, leftMargin=0, rightMargin=0,
                        topMargin=0, bottomMargin=0)

story = []
data = [['Number', 'Random Number']]
for i in range(0, 10000):
    data.append([i, str(random.random()) + '\n' + str(random.random())])

table_style = [
    ('GRID', (0,0), (-1,-1), 1, colors.black),
    ('ALIGN', (0,0), (-1,-1), 'CENTER'),
    ('VALIGN', (0,0), (-1,-1), 'MIDDLE'),
    ('LEFTPADDING', (0,0), (-1,-1), 3),
    ('RIGHTPADDING', (0,0), (-1,-1), 3),
    ('FONTSIZE', (0,0), (-1,-1), 10),
    ('FONTNAME', (0,0), (-1,0), 'Times-Bold'),
]

spreadsheet_table = SpreadsheetTable(data, repeatRows=1)
spreadsheet_table.setStyle(table_style)
s = spreadsheet_table.split(A4[0], A4[1])
for part in s:
    story.append(part)
    story.append(Spacer(0, 10 * mm))
doc.build(story)
```

This generates:

[image]

Comment: I think you have to use the `drawOn` method. But to answer your question properly, could you provide part of your code so we can [reproduce your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: @MuriloSitonio I thought it wouldn't be needed but anyway, I have added it.

Comment: You didn't mention anywhere that [`SpreadSheetTable`](https://github.com/tomaszswiderski/Spreadsheet-Table-for-ReportLab) is a separeted package that was built in python 2. I can't run your code because some syntax of the package raises an erro to my python 3 interpreter.

Comment: @MuriloSitonio Oops! Really sorry. You can find that here : https://github.com/tomaszswiderski/Spreadsheet-Table-for-ReportLab

Comment: I know where to find it (I include the link above as well). What I'm saying is that `SpreadSheetTable` was built in python 2 and I'm using python 3. You should include the `python 2-7` tag.